# What is an "auxiliary variable" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, variables

I'm currently learning about "in-place" algorithms and keep seeing the term "auxiliary variables". I've tried looking it up in several places online but none of the explanations really make sense to me. What are they and how are they used?

Comment: It's not a standard term. Can you provide some context? I think it just means "extra variable" that you use to hold data temporarily.

Comment: Look up the words separately in the dictionary then deduce what they mean in combination.

Comment: @Robert I know I can also count on someone to provide a snarky comment, this one gave me my giggles for the day so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a JavaScript thing.  When discussing in-place algorithms, the term "auxiliary storage" or "auxiliary variables" refers to memory that the algorithm uses that is not part of its input or output.

That would be temporary space needed to swap things around, counters, stack space, etc.

Most in-place algorithms use O(log N) space or less -- less than the size of the input or output.  If that were not true, then it wouldn't matter that they work "in place".

Comment: And quite often they use constant space, `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I'll come back and upvote once i'm able to.